# Stackpanel Object On The Same Line?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**Answered, Thanks to Rohit Vats & Panagiotis Kanavos for their answers worked perfectly!**

I want a ComboBox to go on the same line as a TextBox in a Stackpanel but it just puts it on the line below when the margins are the same.

The ComboBox and the Textboxs are being generated when I click a button.

**C# Code:**

```
int t = 0;
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "Title" + t;
        x.Text = "Title...";
        x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        x.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);


        ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
        y.Name = "Combo" + t;
        y.Text = (t + 1).ToString();
        y.Height = 25;
        y.Width = 45;
        y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        y.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        y.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);

        spStandard.Children.Add(x);
        spStandard.Children.Add(y);


        spStandard.Children.Add(sp);

        t++;


}

    int q = 0;
    private void btnQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "Question" + q;
        x.Text = "Question...";
        x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 500;
        x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        x.AcceptsReturn = true;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(70, 15, 0, 0);
        spStandard.Children.Add(x);
        q++;
}
```

**Picture of what is happening:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Nk8.png

As you can see the Combobox object is getting put under the Textbox when I need it to the left of the Textbox.

Is there any way that i can get around this but by keeping the Stackpanel?

(I asked a question similar to this before but it wasn't for this exact reason.)

Comment: are the StackPanel declared on line 5 (sp) and spStandard supposed to be the same object?

Comment: ps: Building UI from C# is kind of anti-xaml spirit. Use [ItemsControl & DataTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add it in a StackPanel `sp` with Orientation set to `Horizontal` instead of directly adding to outer panel.

Change

```
spStandard.Children.Add(x);
spStandard.Children.Add(y);
```

to

```
sp.Children.Add(x);
sp.Children.Add(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are adding the elements to the wrong StackPanel. Instead of adding them to `sp`, which has `Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal` you add them to spStandard.

You should change:

```
spStandard.Children.Add(x);
spStandard.Children.Add(y);
```

to

```
sp.Children.Add(x);
sp.Children.Add(y);
```